# Creating, editing and saving pdf file (protected by certificate!) in a webbrowser

Tags: pdf

I was wondering if it is possible to open a pdf file (located on a web server) in a web browser, edit it and then save it with the changes. Basically what I need is to open, edit and save a certificate protected pdf file in my web browser, without ever having to download a copy to my desktop. The pdf file contains textfields that needs to be filled out with text before saving the changes.
I know that it is possible to view pdf files in a browser, but im unsure if it is possible to edit it when it is protected by a certificate.

Comment: By certificate, do you mean SSL? I don't think it is possible to edit in the way you ask - that would generally require a PDF editing package to be installed on the user's computer. What you can do is to render a PDF on your server with user input taken from your web application. If the fields are fixed you could use a reporting system such as Jasper, or something like FPDF with PHP to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking can be performed in the following methods: First which is the simplest way is to use Adobe Forms server. If you would like to use your own PDF, you will need to extend reader extensions display the form in a frame and perform cross scripting to tell the form to post itself to the server. Note: read Adobe Reader Extension licensing extending reader extension has restriction on usage.
Obviously you can enable reader extension allow user to download edit and upload the file to your server.
Certified forms means you cannot change the form structure but you can fill the form and save it (if it is reader extension enabled)